# Question about meaning of "single" in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

> **Room rates are pitched at £69 for a single.**
>   <sub>Source: [pitch - Definition from Longman English Dictionary Online](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pitch_2)</sub>

Which of the following is correct?

1. The price of just one room is set to only £69 and not more.
2. The price of one person in a room is only £69. So the price of two individuals for a room will be twice as this price, £138
3. A room with one bedroom is £69, no matter how many persons are in one's company.

Comment: Do you mean "pitched at"? That's an odd way to talk about room rates. In any case, the meaning is #3, with the caveat that there are often restrictions about the maximum number of people who can legally share one room (in the U.S., that's often 5 or 6).

Comment: I'm not very sure, but I think Longman is mainly BrE. This [definition (also by Longman)](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/single_2) for the word *single* (sense 7) says, "a room in a hotel for just one person". Also, Macmillan defines *[single](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/single_2#single_2__4)* in this sense as "a room or bed for one person".

Answer (score 1):

When talking about hotels or motels, at least in U.S., a Single generally means one room with one bed; a Double means one room with two beds.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that the price is given in pounds I assume this is in the U.K.

But for what it's worth, in the U.S., when discussing hotel rooms, a "single room" means a room for one person.

You can't assume that the rate for two people is double the rate for one person. That's just not how hotel pricing works. It will usually be more, but not necessarily double. Just like a 2 pound jar of peanut butter usually does not cost twice as much as a 1 pound jar.

Whether the terminology is the same in the U.K. I have no idea.

Comment: This isn't always correct.  For hotels They usually differentiate between a "Single" which means one bed and "rates based on Single Occupancy" which means you have to pay more (not double) for more than one person.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the establishment (hotel/motel/castle/bed &  breakfast/dude ranch/etc) and *where* in the world you are traveling.

*A single* can refer to *a single bed*. (In AmE this would probably be *a twin bed* instead.)

*A single* can also mean *a single night*.

*Single* can refer to *single occupancy* (one person in a room).

In the USA, what single probably does *not* refer to is *a single room*.

So, your sentence can mean many things, and it is impossible to tell you what it means  without seeing it in context. Did you find this specific sentence on a certain website?

Your third sentence, *a room with one bedroom* does not make much sense. In an American establishment, a *suite* is the type of 'room' you stay in that can have more than one bedroom.

Comment: Thank you so much I just found it in longman dictionary it was an example sentence.

Comment: In the context of a hotel, I've never seen "single" refer to anything other than single occupancy.